# convert string to cultureinfo

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

How can I convert `String` to `CultureInfo`?

```
Cultureinfo ci;
String dummy = dropdownlist.SelectedValue; 
ci = (CultureInfo) dummy; // <- compile time error here
```

> Error: cannot convert string to CultureInfo.

Comment: First problem: C# is case-sensitive. There's no such type as `cultureinfo`, and I suspect you mean `SelectedValue` too. Please make your code as close to reality as possible. Second problem: you can't convert between types arbitrarily like this. Third problem: we don't even know what values you're trying to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just a straightforward creation:

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(dummy);
```

The entire solution:

```
 CultureInfo ci = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownlist.SelectedValue)
   ? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture // Or use other default
   : new CultureInfo(dropdownlist.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You an use [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
```